# iTune-style apps using C#

Tags: c#, iphone

I'd like to develop some wIndows apps using C# that similar to iTune. The app is similar to iTune where it updates information on the iPhone whenever the phone is connected to a windows-based PC/laptop.

From Apple Development Center, my understanding is that I would need the "Accessories SDK" but looking for your guidance on:

- How to start
- What do I need (SDK, ...)

I am using Visual Studio 2008 as development tool.

Thanks in advance.

Dat

Comment: Note that the External Accessories framework is for connecting the iPhone to devices in the Made for iPod program, not for connecting an iPhone to a computer.  It won't help you do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

...you mean...like [doubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/)?
I think DVD Jon already has a head start on you :p

Comment: There's also i-FunBox: http://i-funbox.com/  and PhoneView: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/ , among others, for transferring files to and from the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.

Sorry I should have been more specific. I wasn't thinking of another iTune, file explorer or Media Player. 

The app I have in mind is more of updating contacts on iPhone directly without going through Mobile Me/Exchange.

Also, not looking for an already made app. I'm learning to develop iPhone utilities on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Banshee is an open source iTunes like media player that is written in Mono (Open Source .NET). Have a look here for more details:

http://banshee-project.org/

Comment: Thanks Igor. I searched Banshee before but the last time I checked, they're still working on WIndows version. I'll check again.